# Two semaphores with the same name created at the same time

Tags: c#, semaphore

What happens when two named, i.e. system wide, semaphores are created at the same time?

Say for example you do this:

```
Semaphore sem;

try
{
  sem = Semaphore.OpenExisting("sem1");
}
catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
{
  sem = new Semaphore(0, 1, "sem1");
}
```

What happens if two applications race to try open existing, both fail and one reaches the catch clause before the other? Will the OS be able to host two system wide locks with the same name and treat them as two different locks? <s>It will not merge those locks into one because then why would there be a OpenExisting API?</s> Edit: I was wrong to think this. The two locks will in fact become merged and treated as one.

This is the mother of edge cases of course. Why would it ever occur that two different apps start at the exact same time and both end up executing the OpenExisting call at the same time and end up in this conundrum? But what if I want to cover for that case. Can I?

Edit: I thought this was undocumented but here it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Semaphore__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_String_

A UnauthorizedAccessException will occur because semaphore already exists.

So I need a system wide semaphore in order to synchronize access to a system wide semaphore. This is starting to feel like that time I wanted my winform to always be the top-most window.

Is this case solvable?

Edit2: I followed canton7's link from the comments and found that

"If you need to determine whether or not a named system semaphore was created, use the Semaphore(Int32, Int32, String, Boolean) constructor overload instead."

Edit3: So, here's what I needed to solve my conundrum:

```
Semaphore sem;
bool createdSystemWideSem;

sem = new Semaphore(0, 1, "sem1", out createdSystemWideSem);

if (!createdSystemWideSem)
{
    sem = Semaphore.OpenExisting("sem1");
}
```

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Semaphore__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_String_: "*You can create multiple Semaphore objects that represent the same named system semaphore ... If the named system semaphore already exists, initialCount and maximumCount are not used*". So the second call to `new Semphore(...)` simply opens the existing Semaphore.

Comment: I bet that the first process that enters the critical section wins.

Comment: @canton7 if the second call simply opens the existing semaphore then why is there a OpenExisting API?

Comment: @Marcus In case you want to open an existing semaphore if there is one, but you don't want to create a new one if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: "*A UnauthorizedAccessException will occur because semaphore already exists.*" - as the doc says, this is only if the existing semaphore "*has access control security, and the user does not have FullControl.*". `Semaphore.OpenExisting` throws the same exception if your user doesn't have permission to open the existing semaphore.